# Background image of custom UINavigationBar - Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I want to set the background image of a custom `UINavigationBar`. I googled and found many solutions related to the issue. But still, I am not able to solve the problem.

Here is the image I want to set as background of custom `UINavigationBar`:

[image]

The code that I am using to set the background image:

```
import UIKit

class CustomNavigationBarViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var customNavigationBar: UINavigationBar!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.customNavigationBar.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "TopGradient"), for: .default)
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool
    {
        return true
    }
}
```

The screenshot of the  result that I am getting:

[image]

Instead of the image, I am only getting a gray colored background of `UINavigationBar`.

Comment: Why don't you use a gradient of that color as BG ?

Comment: Also is your image's height greater than 64 px? It might be cropping up the extra height which hides your gradient effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should resize your image. `UINavigationBar` has default height of 64 px. Your image height is more than that.

Check this with correct image size. I have resized the image you were using.

[image]

Hope this will help.